# Identifying these SMD components marked JK1 and 6NLYZ751

Tags: diodes, identification, led-driver

I am looking for the SMD component in the middle marked "JK1".

I also need to identify the bottom diode with the marking "6NLYZ751 or "GNLYZ751" from ST.

[image]

Comment: If can post this picture to digikey forum if nobody recognizes the components here.

Comment: Could you get a better picture showing the markings on D2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't have an exact part number, the component designator of BR1 suggests that the device marked "JK1" is a bridge rectifier--four diodes in one package to save space and assembly time. Most likely any bridge rectifier in the same package (with reasonable current rating) would work.

The other device appears to be an [SM6T56CAY](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/stmicroelectronics/SM6T56CAY/2756529)--here's the picture LCSC [has for it](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/TVS_STMicroelectronics-SM6T56CAY_C3701311.html):
[image]

Thanks @vivier for pointing out that the Y signifies the automotive grade; I had previously found the SM6T56CA, which has a marking of just NL on the second line, but was unable to find the Y.

The writing on the third line is irrelevant; it's probably some combination of date code and factory code, only of interest to ST themselves for traceability.

Comment: Y means that it is the automotive version (SM6T56CAY). datasheet :  https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/sm6t10ay.pdf